# Multiple GitHub accounts on the same device don't work properly while pushing changes

Tags: github, ssh-keys, git-push, account

I have two GitHub accounts. One is for work, another one is for personal usage. When I create a repository on my personal one and git clone it to my machine and try to push changes to my personal account, it is pushed by my work account like a contributor. Both of my accounts have their own SSH keys, but it always asks for the passcode of the work account.

How can I separate them and make it ask me for the passcode of the account I am currently working with?

Please, help.
Thanks in advance.